# Kubernetes python client: authentication problem

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client

I am trying to use the python API for kubernetes and I can't seem to be able to execute the request. I think the pipeline is not clear to me.

I am following the steps here: [Kubernetes python client: authentication issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48151388/kubernetes-python-client-authentication-issue)

On the remote server:

- I setup my service account and generated the secret as described in the link
- I added the token to my code

I am getting connection refused.

- Am I supposed to import any information from the cluster into the local client?
- Is the port okay?

```py
from kubernetes import client, config
def main():
    configuration = client.Configuration() 

    configuration.host = "http://my_ip:8080"
    configuration.api_key_prefix['authorization'] = "Bearer"
    configuration.api_key['authorization'] = "my_token"
    v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
    print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
    ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
    for i in ret.items:
        print("%s\t%s\t%s" %
            (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```sh
   raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='xx.xx.xx.xx', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/pods?watch=False (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x1118e5668>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'
```

Current local client kubectl config view:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters: []
contexts: []
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
```

Answer (score 1):

First, check if kubectl is configured correctly, like in the excerpt below from the [docs here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#configure-kubectl).

> ### Configure kubectl
>
> In order for kubectl to find and access a Kubernetes cluster, it needs a kubeconfig file, which is created automatically when you create a cluster using `kube-up.sh` or successfully deploy a Minikube cluster. [...] By default, kubectl configuration is located at `~/.kube/config`.
>
> ### Check the kubectl configuration
>
> Check that kubectl is properly configured by getting the cluster state:
>
> `kubectl cluster-info`
>
> If you see a URL response, kubectl is correctly configured to access your cluster. 
>   If you see a message similar to the following, kubectl is not correctly configured or not able to connect to a Kubernetes cluster.
>
> `The connection to the server <server-name:port> was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`

---

Because it looks like it isn't connected to a cluster. If it doesn't give back a URL, you can get the `config` file from your remote server (from the `$HOME/.kube` directory).

You can put that file on your local machine, similarly named `$HOME/.kube/config`.

Then you can load that config file in your Python script with:

```
def main():
    config.load_kube_config()
```

Example can be found [here](https://medium.com/programming-kubernetes/building-stuff-with-the-kubernetes-api-part-3-using-python-aea5ab16f627).

Answer (score 0):

You neglected to specify the API server certificate in your configuration. The link you included has the following:

```
configuration.ssl_ca_cert = '<path_to_cluster_ca_certificate>'
```