# Can a pod within my cluster get a list of pods in a service?

Tags: kubernetes

Suppose I have a `Service` within my cluster called `workers`. From `kubectl`, I can list the pods in that service using the selector the service uses:

```
kubectl get pods --selector app=worker
```

Can a pod within the cluster get a list of that service's pods?

Comment: I hope I'm not misreading the question, but you can just run `kubectl` in your pod (or make the equivalent api call). You will need to authenticate using a serviceaccount.

Comment: My pod doesn't have `kubectl` installed. I suppose I could include it in the image, but that seems odd. I'll look into using the API.

Comment: What is actually the reason for getting the list of pods?

Comment: you can look at several [supported client libraries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) and install in your image as per your need.

Comment: Any specific reason for listing all the pods exposed by a particular service ? Could you elaborate a bit more on your use case and explain what you actually want to achieve by that ? Using client libraries seems to me quite reasonable option.

Comment: My thought was to write a custom load balancer for that service, but on further thought, having the pods pull work from RabbitMQ as they're able to handle it makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it quite easily with [Kubernetes Python Client library](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python#kubernetes-python-client). The following code can be run locally as it uses your `.kube/config` file for authentication:

```
from  kubernetes import client , config
config.load_kube_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
list_pods = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(label_selector="app=worker")
for item in list_pods.items:
    print(item.metadata.name)
```

Before that you will need to install the mentioned library, which can be done with `pip`:

```
pip3 install kubernetes
```

For production use I would recommend integrating it with your **python** docker image and of course instead of using `.kube/config` file, you will need to create a `ServiceAccount` for your **client** `Pod` so it can authenticate to **kubernetes API**. This is nicely described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48377444), provided by [krelst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5260676/krelst).